How to find percentage on in SQL?
I have data like this:

I want to find the percentage as a third column for each row, No- 549/(549+342)
Yes - 342/(549+342)
I have tried select Survived, cnt, round(100*(cnt/sum(cnt)), 2) as prcntage from survivalCnt
and also with grouping but nothing seems to work,
I also tried with Partitioning.
Can someone help me, I know its a simple problem, I can't seem to pin point the answer

And which rdmbs do you use?

you need a subquery to run the calculation
SELECT
    Survived,
    cnt,
    (cnt * 100.0 / (SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM survival_data)) AS "%"
FROM
    survival_data;


Thank you so much for the prompt response, and yes it works

can you accept the answer please

You can use a window function, this will be more efficient than a subquery. You also need to convert or multiply by a decimal.
SELECT
    Survived,
    cnt,
    cnt * 100.0 / SUM(cnt) OVER () AS "%"
FROM
    survival_data;

